# How to find a class instance in a running JVM

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out a way to find a class instance inside a working JVM.  The JVM is embedded into another process and an object is created by this process.  The same process executes my Java code.  I do not have a direct access to the Java object reference in my Java code, but I know the class of that object.  I want to find out if there are objects of this class already instantiated in JVM, and if they are, I want to find them (get say an Object array with references to all the instances of this class).  This mechanism can be either a Java API or an JNI API.

I know it is possible since debuggers let me inspect all instances.  I just cannot seem to find the way.

Thanks

Nikita

Comment: Think of all those servlet engines out there.  Would you want an unknown application running in a JBoss or Tomcat or WebSphere or xxx having access to your instanciated objects?

Comment: I would be extremely shocked if this was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody is curious, It is possible and I am doing it now using JVMTI.  Not straightforward, but very doable.  You can look at my other post about jvmti and you will find the answer.

[Perplexed by jvmti object allocation callback behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856861/perplexed-by-jvmti-object-allocation-callback-behavior)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [Java Instrumentation APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html).

Comment: I am not finding anything in instrumentation package that would give me access to already instantiated objects.  It lets me fiddle with classes and class loading, but not with objects.  Any more thoughts???  Thanks

Comment: @NikitaVisnevski see this method `getAllLoadedClasses()` or `getInitiatedClasses(..)`

Comment: (Reaching here) I think you may need to spec an instrumentation agent on your (embedded) JVM startup and trap various calls e.g. new X().

Comment: These methods give me Classes that have been loaded, not the object instances of these classes.  To make it simple, I would need something that would return me Object[], not Class[].  Is there a way to get all current instances of a Class?  Specifically, if I have say 20 instances of class String, how can I get the array of these 20 instances?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible from another process using the debug interface

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/

However, if I understand your requirement correctly, you would need your process to debug itself which is probably not going to work.