# Perplexed by jvmti object allocation callback behavior

Tags: java, jvmti

Can anybody explain to me why can I get a callback when jvm allocates some java objects, but not others?  Here is what I am doing:

```
static jvmtiCapabilities    capa;
static jvmtiEnv*            jvmti                   = NULL;
static const char*          fileName                = "C:\\temp\\ObjectInitCallbackDump.txt";
static ofstream             outFileStream;

void JNICALL callbackObjectAllocation ( jvmtiEnv*   jvmti_env, 
                                        JNIEnv*     jni_env,
                                        jthread     thread,
                                        jobject     object,
                                        jclass      object_klass,
                                        jlong       size            )
{
    char*       generic_ptr_class;
    char*       class_name;
    jvmtiError  error;

    error = jvmti_env->GetClassSignature(object_klass, &class_name, &generic_ptr_class);
    if (check_jvmti_error(jvmti_env, error, "Failed to get class signature")) {
        return;
    }
    outFileStream << class_name << std::endl;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Agent_OnLoad(JavaVM *jvm, char *options, void *reserved) {
    jint                result;
    jvmtiError          error;
    jvmtiEventCallbacks callbacks;

    outFileStream.open(fileName,ios::trunc);

    result  = jvm->GetEnv((void**) &jvmti, JVMTI_VERSION_1_1);
    if (result != JNI_OK || jvmti == NULL) {
        printf("error\n");
        return JNI_ERR;
    } else {
        printf("loaded agent\n");
    }

    (void) memset(&capa, 0, sizeof(jvmtiCapabilities));
    capa.can_generate_vm_object_alloc_events        = 1;

    error = jvmti->AddCapabilities(&capa);
    if (check_jvmti_error(jvmti, error, "Unable to set capabilities") != JNI_OK) {
        return JNI_ERR;
    }

    (void) memset(&callbacks, 0, sizeof(callbacks));
    callbacks.VMObjectAlloc         = &callbackObjectAllocation;

    error = jvmti->SetEventCallbacks(&callbacks, (jint) sizeof(callbacks));
    if (check_jvmti_error(jvmti, error, "Unable to set callbacks") != JNI_OK) {
        return JNI_ERR;
    }

    error = jvmti->SetEventNotificationMode(    JVMTI_ENABLE,
                                                JVMTI_EVENT_VM_OBJECT_ALLOC,
                                                (jthread) NULL);
    if (check_jvmti_error(jvmti, error,
            "Unable to set method entry notifications") != JNI_OK) {
        return JNI_ERR;
    }

    return JNI_OK;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Agent_OnUnload(JavaVM *vm) {
    outFileStream.close();
}
```

When I examine the file that I create, I do not see the classes that I am interested in, although I know they are there and NetBeans tells me there is exactly one instance of that class in the jvm.  Any thoughts???

Nikita

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For performance reasons, the JVMTI only supports allocation events for objects that cannot be detected through bytecode instrumentation (BCI), as explained in the JVMTI `VMObjectAlloc`  event documentation. This means that the event will not be triggered for most object allocations. I assume that the allocations you are missing fall within that category.

Fortunately, it's not really too difficult to intercept all object allocations using BCI. The [HeapTracker](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/tip/src/share/demo/jvmti/heapTracker/) demo illustrates precisely how to intercept all object allocations in a JVMTI agent using [java_crw_demo](https://blogs.oracle.com/kto/entry/a_short_java_crw_demo) in addition to the `VMObjectAlloc` events.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are just not hitting your check?
If this is the code you actually run then you have a bug; you missed the ; at the end of the object
Your compare should be like this:

```
if (strcmp(class_name,"Ljavax/swing/JFrame;") == 0) {
    printf("Got the sucker!!!");
}
```

Comment: Actually I have been using another function that finds a sub-string in a given string, but I even changed the strategy and dumped every single class descriptor that I could extract in the callbackObjectAllocation into a text file and then examined that file.  I gae something like 4MB of text with hundreds of thousands of classes, but none of the ones I am interested in, even though I plainly see them on the screen.  So, I am completely puzzled, what makes some objects special that their allocation causes this event, and others to not cause it.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I have just updated the listing to a more representative example.  Hope somebody can help.  It is mostly annoying to me that there is something in that mechanism I do not understand.  Thanks